# Django on OpenShift: "no such table"

Tags: django, sqlite, openshift

I get this kind of error when I try to load any page.

Running `sqlall` throw the ssh shows the database shema fine.

I have such a settings file:

```
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    # os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_*'] variables can be used with databases created
    # with rhc cartridge add (see /README in this git repo)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
```

And I have a copy of my database in the /data directory.

Also, I have such startup hooks:

```
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/$cartridge_type/virtenv/bin/activate

if [ ! -f $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/sqlite3.db ]
then
    echo "Copying $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/openshift/sqlite3.db to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR"
    cp "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/sqlite3.db $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR".openshift/action_hooks/secure_db.py | tee ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/CREDENTIALS
else
    echo "Executing 'python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/openshift/manage.py syncdb --noinput'"
    python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/manage.py syncdb --noinput
fi

echo "Executing 'python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/openshift/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'"
python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

So everything seems to be fine.

(However, it seems to me that startup hooks havn't been started.)

**edit** : I don't know why, but after manual coping of database into /data - it **works fine**!

Comment: is there a migration that you forgot to run on OpenShift?

Comment: @karthikr, nope. south said that database was up to date.

Comment: another "silly" question - was the migration uploaded to the production server ?

Comment: @karthikr, I've run south on the server trought ssh, so it must have been there. It seems to me that deploy hook updates the schema of \wsgi\sqlite.db, but doesn't change \data\sqlite.db. As it it mentioned in the question: after cping manually sqlite.db into \data it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a quickstart or building these out?  Some things to check is to ensure that the hooks added are executable (chmod +x).  Those echo statements should show up in your git push logs/output as that's when these build/deploy hooks are executed.
Glad things are working for you now.